# Remove duplicates only works as a separate macro outside of debug mode for VBA

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, event-handling

I'm pulling in information from a Nasdaq data center and want it to auto update whenever I change my ad hoc tickers. I have the VBA working and when I pull the information every ticker comes with a duplicate. Wanted to simply call another sub to remove the duplicate automatically after the data is pulled. If I step one line at a time it works fine. When I run the macro though it doesn't eliminate the duplicates. I have to run it separately. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Start event catalyst
    Dim VRange As Range
    Set VRange = Me.Range("I1:I11")
    If Union(Target, VRange).Address = VRange.Address Then Call SF
    
End Sub

Sub SF()
'Call API
With Sheets("meta")
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    .Range("A13:P35").ClearContents
    .Range("A13").Value = .Range("A5").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End With
   
    Call Remove
    
End Sub

Sub Remove()
'Check and remove duplicates
With Sheets("meta")
    
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
     .Range("A13:P36").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `.Range("A13:P36")` filled after `.Range("A13:P35").ClearContents` ?

Comment: its P35, I had been moving things around to try and have an extra row but to no avail. Still doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: I meant why is there no API call in between the `.ClearContents` and the `Call Remove`, It looks to be commented out at line 1 of SF.

Comment: Call api is actually a comment. Nasdaqs data link contains an excel addin that allows me to just press enter on the cell or the equivalent for me is when I change any ticker in my range. It automatically calls the api based on nasdaqs addin function.

Comment: Is the ticker range within A13:P36 ?

Comment: The list of tickers are in cells above the range but they do get copied into A13 as part of the API which triggers the event and call.

Comment: `If Union(Target, VRange).Address = VRange.Address Then Call SF` - Is that checking for a change(target) is within `Range("I1:I11")` ?

Comment: Yup, those are the cells I have my tickers in. Then that gets copied into cell A13 as part of the API call. This all gets event changed by the change in any value in the cells I1:I11. It's strange though, say I change the coulmn I filter by for remove duplicates. Some of them work all though its not the field I would need to edit by. I feel it has something to do with the lag from calling the API. I tried doing in application wait but it doesn't help even when I put it later in the code.   As of now I just added the Macro for removing duplicate to a button, still annoys me it wont automate.